# Export HTML table column to text list

Tags: html, parsing

I'd like to export/copy table columns from two sites, Allmusic and Wikipedia, in the form of a text list. Both columns (one for each site) contain the track listing for a particular music album. I'd like to have the text lists in this form:

```
    SongTitle1
    SongTitle2
    etc.
```

As I understand it, both sites do not have an API. At least, in the case of Allmusic I believe  that the API is only accessable for paid subscribers. This leaves me with the option of scraping directly from the HTML page.

What would be the easiest way to achieve this? Preferably, I'd like something light-weight like a Firefox add-on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done a lot of work with online annual reports (lots of tables), and actually loading the page into (cough, ahem) Dreamweaver or MS Word gives you the easiest interface to select and copy columns from tables.

Comment: Hehe I believe you when you say you've done a lot of work related to this. Turns out the best way is sometimes the easiest way :)